# How to add existing form into another project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

I am trying to add an existing Form into my project. But when I try to run it is saying that '`MyProject.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for  //filename`

Then how to reuse an existing form into another project?

Comment: Code where the error is located?

Comment: The forum is referring to the `filename` entry in the project's resources it came from. You need to transfer those over too.

Comment: What is the namespace of the imported form? You should consider that point to make some proper using statements.

Comment: A form is a **class**, not a resource.  Use it like you use any class in another assembly.  Add a reference to the assembly or the project and use the *new* operator to create an instance of the class.